# WiX quiet execution of .cmd file

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

When using WixQuietExec the command line file I am trying to launch does not appear to run during installation.

My reason for doing this is that the installer I am building necessitates running a number of .exe/.bat files in a particular sequence to build correctly.

**.wxs file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="immediateExecution" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="test" UpgradeCode="8b6b82f7-ecbb-426d-bd9a-6fb7548ac349">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="immediateExecution" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="immediateExecution" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

    </ComponentGroup>
    <Property Id="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value="blankfile.cmd"/>
    <CustomAction Id="QtExecExample" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
       <Custom Action="QtExecExample" Sequence="1"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

blankfile.cmd

```
cd C:\Users\ljn\Desktop
copy NUL EMptyFile.txt
```

This is obviously a test case to check the functionality can be achieved in WiX. From the documentation it seems this should be easily achievable, yet the example here is not producing the desired result. Is there something wrong with the .wxs file? Please bear in mind that the utils reference has been added correctly in VS.

Comment: What are the bat files and exe files doing? It is very bad practice to run batch file during installation. Transaction-wise and reliability-wise. Logging is bad, rollback basically not supported, impersonation and runtime context complicated. You should implement proper custom actions. Please describe what the batch files and exe files do, and how many there are.

Comment: I'm migrating a large collection of software that relies on many separate .jar executions in build. Analysing these and fully moving to c# custom actions may perhaps be a good longer term solution. But for the moment, executing these jars sequentially from a .bat or .cmd file seemed to be a good short-term solution. I checked the msi extensions, and the java support only appears to go as far as archiving and extracting.